# Inconsistency between postgres and hibernate

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Inconsistency between hibernate and postres.
Consider we have table student having 2 columns id(Primary Key) and name. Perform the following concurrent query on table

POSTGRES:

```
1. BEGIN;                                                 BEGIN;
2. SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;          SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
3. SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE ID = 2;                   SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE ID = 1;
4. INSERT INTO STUDENTS(ID, NAME) VALUES(2, 'TOM');       INSERT INTO STUDENTS(ID, NAME) VALUES(1, 'HANK');                               
5. COMMIT;                                                COMMIT;
```

Started 2 sessions of postres Perform line 1 - 4 on the right in and then in 2nd session run line 1-4 on the left and then commit both the transactions and both of them commits successfully.

HIBERNATE:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, rollbackFor = [Exception::class])
    fun addStudent(id: Long, name: String) {
        val alreadyPresentStudent = studentsRepository.findByIdOrNull(id)
        if (alreadyPresentStudent != null) return
        val student = Student().apply {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name
        }
        studentsRepository.save(student)
    }
```

Here when I call the above method with addStudent(1, "HANK") and before 1st transaction commits we call addStudent(2, "TOM"). The first gets flushed in the db, but I get following error for 2nd

```
"Could not execute because of read/write dependencies betweeen transactions"
```

Comment: Does `ID` of your table is sequence generator or something? Also, in case of hibernate, are you calling second `addStudent(..)` within same session?

Comment: @AshishPatil is a sequence generator, I am calling in different session